Matplotlib Boxplots with different colours based on a specific column in pandas dataframe
I am trying to change this plot

to match this style

Changes required are as follows:

change colour of individual boxes for oxide to red, transition to green and fresh to blue
add legend for oxide, transition and fresh
Simplify x-axis to include only the elements

Here is an excerpt of my data:
Oxidation   Elements    GAI
1.OXIDE Ag_ppm  1
2.TRANS Ag_ppm  1
2.TRANS Ag_ppm  0
2.TRANS Ag_ppm  2
2.TRANS Ag_ppm  2
2.TRANS Ag_ppm  1
3.FRESH Ag_ppm  2
3.FRESH Ag_ppm  0
3.FRESH Ag_ppm  0
3.FRESH Ag_ppm  1
3.FRESH Ag_ppm  0
3.FRESH Ag_ppm  0
1.OXIDE Ag_ppm  0
1.OXIDE Ag_ppm  1
1.OXIDE Ag_ppm  0
1.OXIDE Ag_ppm  0
1.OXIDE Ag_ppm  0
1.OXIDE Ag_ppm  0
1.OXIDE Cu_ppm  1
2.TRANS Cu_ppm  1
2.TRANS Cu_ppm  1
2.TRANS Cu_ppm  1
2.TRANS Cu_ppm  2
2.TRANS Cu_ppm  1
3.FRESH Cu_ppm  2
3.FRESH Cu_ppm  1
3.FRESH Cu_ppm  2
3.FRESH Cu_ppm  2
3.FRESH Cu_ppm  2
3.FRESH Cu_ppm  1
3.FRESH Cu_ppm  2
1.OXIDE Cu_ppm  3
1.OXIDE Cu_ppm  3
1.OXIDE Cu_ppm  3
1.OXIDE Cu_ppm  4
1.OXIDE Cu_ppm  2
1.OXIDE Mg_pct  1
1.OXIDE Mg_pct  1
1.OXIDE Mg_pct  3
1.OXIDE Mg_pct  2
1.OXIDE Mg_pct  1
1.OXIDE Mg_pct  1
1.OXIDE Mg_pct  2
1.OXIDE Mg_pct  2
2.TRANS Mg_pct  2
2.TRANS Mg_pct  2
2.TRANS Mg_pct  2
2.TRANS Mg_pct  2
2.TRANS Mg_pct  2
3.FRESH Mg_pct  2
3.FRESH Mg_pct  2
3.FRESH Mg_pct  2
3.FRESH Mg_pct  2
3.FRESH Mg_pct  2


Here is my current script:
# Plot boxplots
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,8))

# Box plot properties
mean = dict(marker = 'x', mec = 'Black', ms = 9)
median=dict(color ="Black", lw=1.2)
whisker=dict(color ="Black", lw=1.2)
cap=dict(color ="Black", lw=1.2)
flier=dict(markerfacecolor= 'green', ms=10)

key_label = ['Ag','Cu','Mg']
key_ox = ['Oxide','Transition','Fresh','Oxide','Transition','Fresh','Oxide','Transition','Fresh']
col_ox = ['r','g','b','r','g','b','r','g','b']

gai_waste.boxplot(ax=ax, by = ['Elements', 'Oxidation'], column =["GAI"],
                  color = '#ADD8E6', patch_artist=True, whis=[10, 90], #widths=0.2,
                  whiskerprops = whisker, showmeans=True, meanprops = mean, medianprops=median, capprops = cap, showfliers=False,
                  grid = True, rot = 90, fontsize = 'medium')

plt.ylabel("GAI", fontsize = 'x-large', fontname='Calibri', weight='bold')
plt.xlabel(None)
plt.yticks(fontsize = 'large', fontname='Calibri')
plt.xticks(np.arange(1, 10, 1),labels=key_ox,ha='center',fontsize = 'large', fontname='Calibri', rotation = 0)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(FormatStrFormatter('%.0f'))
plt.grid(True, which='both', color='lightgrey',ls = '--')
plt.suptitle('')
plt.title('')

x=2
for i in range(3):
    plt.text(x = x , y = -5.5, s = str(key_label[i]),horizontalalignment='center', fontsize = 'x-large', weight='bold')
    x+=3

I have attempted to use seaborn to create this plot:

but I find I am not able to add different percentiles and customise axes. Here is the seaborn script:
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (20,8))

sns.set_theme(style="ticks", palette="pastel")

sns.boxplot(data=gai_waste, x='Elements', y='GAI', hue='Oxidation', palette=['r','g','b'],
            width=0.5, dodge=True, ax=ax, whis=[10,90], showfliers=False , whiskerprops = whisker, medianprops=median,
            showmeans=True,meanprops=mean)
sns.despine(offset=10, trim=True)
plt.xlabel(None)

#add legend image
img = plt.imread("legend2.jpg")
ab = AnnotationBbox(OffsetImage(img, zoom=0.1), (5,-2.5), frameon=True)
ax.add_artist(ab)


Thanks in advance for your help!

When you post a request for your data and a graph, and then post your full code, you are asking someone to read your code and your request, fix your code as requested  and plot the graph. In short, you're asking someone to do your work for you, and I don't think that's a question. If you're going to ask questions, isolate each issue with a simple sample.

Did you consider seaborn with sns.boxplot(..., hue='oxidation')? It's quite some work to mimick with pure matplotlib what seaborn does in one line.

As is pointed out in the comments matplotlib is not the best solution and this is why the preferred way would be seaborn, but if you absolutely must, then here is my suggestion:
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from matplotlib.ticker import FormatStrFormatter
import pandas as pd

data = {
    'Oxidation': ['OXIDE', 'TRANS', 'TRANS', 'TRANS', 'TRANS', 'TRANS', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE', 'TRANS', 'TRANS', 'TRANS', 'TRANS', 'TRANS', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE'],
    'Elements': ['Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Mg_pct', 'Mg_pct', 'Mg_pct', 'Mg_pct', 'Mg_pct'],
    'GAI': np.random.randint(0, 5, 36)
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 8))

colors = {'OXIDE': 'red', 'TRANS': 'green', 'FRESH': 'blue'}

boxprops = dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=1.5)
medianprops = dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=1.5, color='k')
meanprops = dict(marker='X', markerfacecolor='black', markeredgecolor='black')
whiskerprops = dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=1.5)
capprops = dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=1.5)
flierprops = dict(marker='o', color='k', alpha=0.5)

for label, df_group in df.groupby('Elements'):
    element_index = np.unique(df['Elements']).tolist().index(label)
    for oxidation, group in df_group.groupby('Oxidation'):
        ax.boxplot(group['GAI'], positions=[element_index], widths=0.6,
                   boxprops=dict(facecolor=colors[oxidation], linestyle='-', linewidth=1.5),
                   medianprops=medianprops, meanprops=meanprops, whiskerprops=whiskerprops,
                   capprops=capprops, flierprops=flierprops, patch_artist=True)

element_labels = [el.split('_')[0] for el in np.unique(df['Elements'])]
ax.set_xticks(range(len(element_labels)))
ax.set_xticklabels(element_labels, fontsize='large', fontname='Calibri', rotation=0)

from matplotlib.patches import Patch
legend_elements = [Patch(facecolor=colors[name], label=name) for name in ['OXIDE', 'TRANS', 'FRESH']]
ax.legend(handles=legend_elements, loc='upper right')

plt.ylabel("GAI", fontsize='x-large', fontname='Calibri', weight='bold')
plt.yticks(fontsize='large', fontname='Calibri')
plt.grid(True, which='both', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5, color='grey', axis='y')
plt.title('Distribution of GAI by Element and Oxidation Phase', fontsize=14)

plt.show()


which gives

Updatez/b>: To avoid overlapping boxes
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib.patches import Patch

data = {
    'Oxidation': ['OXIDE', 'TRANS', 'TRANS', 'TRANS', 'TRANS', 'TRANS', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE', 'TRANS', 'TRANS', 'TRANS', 'TRANS', 'TRANS', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'FRESH', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE', 'OXIDE'],
    'Elements': ['Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Ag_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Cu_ppm', 'Mg_pct', 'Mg_pct', 'Mg_pct', 'Mg_pct', 'Mg_pct'],
    'GAI': np.random.randint(0, 5, 36)
}
df = pd.DataFrame(data)

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(20, 8))

colors = {'OXIDE': 'red', 'TRANS': 'green', 'FRESH': 'blue'}

boxprops = dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=1.5)
medianprops = dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=1.5, color='k')
meanprops = dict(marker='X', markerfacecolor='black', markeredgecolor='black')
whiskerprops = dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=1.5)
capprops = dict(linestyle='-', linewidth=1.5)
flierprops = dict(marker='o', color='k', alpha=0.5)

offsets = {'OXIDE': -0.2, 'TRANS': 0, 'FRESH': 0.2}
width = 0.2

element_labels = [el.split('_')[0] for el in np.unique(df['Elements'])]
element_positions = np.arange(len(element_labels))

for label, df_group in df.groupby('Elements'):
    element_index = element_labels.index(label.split('_')[0])
    for oxidation, group in df_group.groupby('Oxidation'):
        pos = element_index + offsets[oxidation]
        ax.boxplot(group['GAI'], positions=[pos], widths=width,
                   boxprops=dict(facecolor=colors[oxidation], linestyle='-', linewidth=1.5),
                   medianprops=medianprops, meanprops=meanprops, whiskerprops=whiskerprops,
                   capprops=capprops, flierprops=flierprops, patch_artist=True)

ax.set_xticks(element_positions)
ax.set_xticklabels(element_labels, fontsize='large', fontname='Calibri', rotation=0)

legend_elements = [Patch(facecolor=colors[name], label=name) for name in ['OXIDE', 'TRANS', 'FRESH']]
ax.legend(handles=legend_elements, loc='upper right')

plt.ylabel("GAI", fontsize='x-large', fontname='Calibri', weight='bold')
plt.yticks(fontsize='large', fontname='Calibri')
plt.grid(True, which='both', linestyle='--', linewidth=0.5, color='grey', axis='y')
plt.title('Distribution of GAI by Element and Oxidation Phase', fontsize=14)

plt.show()

which gives


Thanks. How do I avoid boxes overlapping?
